# Shoulda/RSpec: Make sure that validation message "xxx" is on :base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rspec, shoulda

I'm still pretty confused about what is magic behind stuff like `it { should have(1).error_on(:base) }` and what's a specific Shoulda matcher.

I'd like to make sure that `:base` contains the error message "xxx", so how should I do this?

```
it "should contain error message 'xxx'" do
  contact.valid?
  contact.errors[:base].should include('xxx')
end
```

Is this "the way to go", or is there a better one? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right, it's looking good. Inline rspec tests are using subject. You could rewrite your test like this:

```
describe 'my method' do
  before { contact.valid? }

  context 'contact is not valid' do
    subject { contact.errors[:base] }
    it { should include 'xxx' }
  end
end
```

The should method is called on the subject. It can be more readable sometimes. And you don't have to write descriptions for specs that are self-explanatory ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the hint with subject and before filters.

Comment: More concise: it { subject.errors[:base].should include 'xxx' }

Comment: .error[:whatever] now returns an array, so include doesn't work unless you are matching the entire string.