# Why is RSpec lying to me about errors on my active model object?

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

## code

```
class Foo
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  def bar
    errors.add(:base, 'WHAT THE HELL!?')
  end
end
```

## spec

```
describe 'nonsense' do
  specify do
    foo = Foo.new
    foo.bar
    expect(foo).to have(1).error_on(:base)
  end
end
```

## output

```
 Failure/Error: specify { expect(foo).to have(1).error_on(:base) }
   expected 1 error on :base, got 0
```

## real proof of nonsense:

```
describe 'nonsense' do
  specify do
    foo = Foo.new
    foo.bar
    pus foo.errors.inspect
    expect(foo).to have(1).error_on(:base)
  end
end

===>
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00000109ba51a8 @base=#<Foo:0x00000109ba51f8 @errors=#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00000109ba51a8 ...>>, @messages={:base=>["WHAT THE HELL!?"]}>
```

## omg...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shoulda/RSpec: Make sure that validation message "xxx" is on :base](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453152/shoulda-rspec-make-sure-that-validation-message-xxx-is-on-base)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that if you don't call the "valid?" method prior to using the "have(n).errors_on" matcher in a spec, it will always return false, even if your errors object has stuff in it!